Generator prime movers vs. motor starting voltage drop: why does it matter what's spinning the alternator?
I was playing around in Cummins' GenSize tool with an example 5HP fire pump load to try to get an idea for just how large a generator would be needed to start a small fire pump, and found something very interesting.  As it turns out, while a 40kW diesel genset is adequate to meet the NEC fire pump starting voltage dip maximum of 15%, the matching model with a gaseous fueled (spark ignited) prime mover flunks out with a whopping 26% starting voltage dip, according to GenSize.
So, I started looking into why this is the case, and it seems quite baffling to me at the first glance.   While the spark-ignited QSJ2.4 prime mover in the C40N6 only has 2.4L of displacement compared to the 3.3L displacement of the 4BT3.3-G5 diesel in the C40D6, the SI prime mover is rated for 70hp while the diesel only makes 69hp, and the two gensets are specified to use the same CA115-V14 alternator at the same voltage (208Y/120, in a B946 option configuration).  Furthermore, this comparison holds regardless of the excitation method specified (EBS or shunt).
Can someone explain to me why a SI prime mover of a given size would struggle with a load specification (5HP, 208Y/120 motor at 15% allowable starting voltage dip) that a diesel prime mover of the same size (at least in nameplate HP) would have no difficulty with, given that both are turning identical alternators at the same 1800 RPM?  Perhaps it has to do with the diesel developing more torque at that RPM point?
(And if you're wondering why I'm asking this instead of just going with the herd and picking out a diesel for the application, well...diesel fuel really doesn't store the way it used to.  The reasons why have to do with desulfurization and refining standards, and are probably for the best given that nobody likes battery leakage raining on their head, for that matter, but still...it's quite annoying and unnecessarily-polluting to have to run one's genset more than they absolutely need to just to turn over your fuel supply.)

I have no hard data, but my guesses would revolve around things like the diesel having a larger flywheel and a flatter torque curve.

Rotating mass and torque - you need to check more detail, including the power and torque curves.

@SolarMike -- ...which I haven't been able to find for either prime mover mentioned in the question

Starting current can be 5-8 times rated current for a 3-phase motor.  You need to provide links to motor datasheet and generators.

@StainlessSteelRat -- example generators are the Cummins C40N6 and C40D6 but the specsheets aren't enough detail to judge by, although I'll edit them in anyway.  Motor locked rotor behavior, though, needs to come from NEC Table 430.251(B)

Use a wye delta starter to reduce starting current.

@StainlessSteelRat -- fire pump setups invariably have to either meet starting voltage dip requirements on an across the line start or demonstrate successful starting on generator power with the controller in bypass (see NEC 695.7)

It's simply that the diesel has a much greater peak power and torque - more "headroom" vs the LPG engine. They run very clean and are often speced closer to peak power because of the their excellent reliability and low maintenance requirements. If you had comparable displacements,  the issue would mostly go away. The engines also apparently have different governor setups, for what ever reason . The LPG unit just wasn't designed for heavy load starting. Fuel efficiency at part throttle tends to be better for diesels, so a few extra cubes doesn't hurt fuel economy as much.
